# What exactly is the pi-rho-omega meson interaction vertex?

Tags: mesons

In the literature that I am currently aware of, the pi-rho-omega meson interaction vertex in chiral perturbation theory is stated as:

$$
  (1)
  \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;
  g_{\rho \pi \omega}
  \;
  \epsilon^{\mu_1 \mu_2 \nu_1 \nu_2} 
  \langle 
    \partial_{\mu_1} \rho_{\mu_2} \cdot \pi
  \rangle 
  \partial_{\nu_1} \omega_{\nu_2}
$$

and similarly for the omega-meson replaced by a photon:

$$
  (1')
  \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;
  g_{\rho \pi \gamma}
  \;
  \epsilon^{\mu_1 \mu_2 \nu_1 \nu_2} 
  \langle 
    \partial_{\mu_1} \rho_{\mu_2} \cdot \pi
  \rangle 
  \partial_{\nu_1} A_{\nu_2}
$$

(where angular brackets are to denote the trace over flavor indices).

An ancient claim to this extent is in Renard 69 ([doi:10.1007/BF02758844](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02758844)). More recent authors admit that this interaction ought to be derived from the chiral anomaly WZW term, for instance Gokalp et al. 03 ([arXiv:hep-ph/0306044](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0306044)).

A hint that there is fine-print to this derivation appears in

- D. Garcia Gudino, G. Toledo Sanchez: "The $\omega \rho \pi$ coupling in the VMD model revisited", Int. J. Mod. Phys. A 27, 1250101(2012) ([arXiv:1106.1467](https://arxiv.org/abs/1106.1467))

where on p. 2 the term appears with an ellipses "$+ \cdots$", saying that "additional terms which allow to preserve gauge invariance are not shown".

**So what's the full $\rho$-$\omega$-$\pi$-interaction vertex?**

Unfortunately, it is tradition to display the chiral WZW term as a long messy soup of summands. Luckily, there is an exception: In

- Roland Kaiser: "Anomalies and WZW-term of two-flavour QCD", Phys. Rev. D63:076010, 2001 ([arXiv:hep-ph/0011377](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0011377))

the 2-flavor WZW term is given in decent form (equation (12)). Expanding out the exponentiated pion field $U = e^{i \vec \pi / f_\pi} = 1 + i/f_\pi \vec \pi + \cdots$ in Kaiser's equation (12), this gives the relevant anomalous interaction vertices, to first order in $\pi$, to be linear combinations of terms of this form:

$$
  (2)
  \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;
  \epsilon^{\mu_1 \mu_2 \nu_1 \nu_2}
  \langle V_{\mu_1} \cdot \partial_{\mu_2}\pi \rangle \langle \partial_{\nu_1} V_{\nu_2} \rangle
$$

and of this form:

$$
  (3)
  \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;
  \epsilon^{\mu_1 \mu_2 \nu_1 \nu_2}
  \langle V_{\mu_1} \cdot V_{\mu_2} \cdot \pi \rangle \langle \partial_{\nu_1} V_{\nu_2} \rangle
$$

where now $V$ denotes any vector meson (omega, or rho, or $a_1$ or photon)

Here (2) is indeed proportional to (1), after a partial integration.

**Question 1**: But how about the interactions due to the vertices of the form (3)? Does anyone discuss these?

**Question 2**: If we'd take the point of view of "hidden local symmetry", and moreover assume that the "vector meson field strength" $D_V V := d V + \frac{1}{2}[V \wedge V]$ vanishes (?) then the respective term (3) becomes proportional to (1), too. Or else, it differs by a term proportional to that field strength $D_V V$, which maybe we may assume to be negligible, in practice? Is that a point of view implicit in the practice of meson physics?

Comment: Q1: 4 meson vertex? How do you measure it or determine it? Not decay, nor scattering...

Comment: Thanks, but could you expand? This 4-meson term is certainly present in the Lagrangian, as part of the WZW term. You are saying it is not physically observable?

Comment: unlike chiral perturbation theory, vector dominance is a dark phenomenological art driven by data.... Try [Bando-Kugo-Yamawaki 1988](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0370157388900191)...

Comment: Thanks. I am aware of BKY88. In Sec. 7.3 they start out recalling the general WZW term, and then on p. 297 they "propose" a parameter choice whose only direct quartic interaction is pi -> 3 gamma, true. But they admit there are "other choices" by Meissner et al.

Comment: Indeed, the quartic pi-omega-rho coupling term that I am asking about does appear in phenomenological work in various articles:
-- equation (6) in Meissner-Zahed 86 doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.56.1035
-- equation (2.18) in Meissner-Kaiser-Weise 87 doi.org/10.1016/0375-9474(87)90463-5
-- equation (2.45) in Meissner 88 doi.org/10.1016/0370-1573(88)90090-7
-- equation (12) in Kaiser 01 arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0011377
-- So what's the deal?

Comment: I'm not an expert. There is no firm "theory" on these things. Just phenomenological fits and stabs in the dark...  It is a different country. The whole premise of BKY is to "try something" and hope nature likes it for obscure reasons.

Comment: All right. Just to say that I am not concerned with BKY's assumptions (just reacted to you pointing me there) but simply with the WZW term, whose general form is fixed by the chiral anomaly, independently of how the rest of the EFT is modeled. The chiral anomaly WZW term necessarily has a quartic piece. But I gather now that there is a sociological disconnect between this theoretical deduction and the practice of meson scattering theory.

Comment: Maybe we are talking at cross purposes: The WZW term *only* involves pseudoscalars, and gauge fields when gauged. Now, when *stretched* by VDM, it can, informally, improperly, include vector mesons, but it all then becomes subjective. The higher-order pseudoscalar terms are dictated by symmetry and can be probed, as in Donoghue & Holstein's book, but any vector meson talk is driven by strict "pragmatic" phenomenology.

Comment: Thanks for your patience. I may indeed be underappreciating the amount wiggle room involved. To help me, please let's jointly look again at Kaiser's review arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0011377 of what he presents as a strict derivation of the WZW term, including (pseudo-)vector mesons, for 2-flavor QCD -- because that account is nicely streamlined to the point. Where in that derivation is a subjective assumption slipped in? (Maybe you would say it's right away in the second line of (2)?)

Comment: Ach, Urs, that's exactly where I don't want to go: in Witten's ref [7] language, "two-flavor WZW in 4D" is an oxymoron, as the *d* coefficient of SU(2) is strictly zero: that was largely the point of his triumph, that abstract topology for 3 flavors had in it the essence of $\pi\to \gamma \gamma $, ostensibly ignorant of strangeness!  Gasser Leutwyler effective actions for flavor chiral anomalies might be fine for you to study, but most physicists would balk at calling them WZW... Most of them understand by that term Witten's term consisting of pseudo scalars.

Comment: How G-L derive QCD effective lagrangians for flavor chiral anomalies out of quark interpolating fields is probably state-of-the art, and I know of no superior alternatives, but it is not the topological slam dunk for chiral models that most, including myself, understand by WZW. And, no, I do not have a ready critique concerning the soft spots of G-L... Sorry I can't be more helpful, but "I've watched grown men cry" at this, to speak metaphorically...